# Getting the means and sum of columns of a dataframe on the basis of randomly selected bins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

data

```
Index   ID  AA  BB  CC  BIN
0       Z1  10  11  12  1
1       Z1  0   12  13  1
2       Z1  20  13  14  2
3       Z1  34  14  15  3
4       Z1  54  52  16  3
5       Z1  67  53  17  3
6       Z7  45  54  18  1
7       Z7  34  55  19  2
8       Z7  45  56  57  2
9       Z7  45  56  58  3
10      Z7  67  67  59  3
```

I want to get a dataframe that looks like below

data2

```
ID   AA_SUM_12  AA_MEAN_12  BB_SUM_12  BB_MEAN_12  CC_SUM_12  CC_MEAN_12
Z1   30         10          36         12          39         13
Z7   124        41.33       165        55          94         31.33
```

Where `SUM_12` gives a sum where `'BIN' = 1 and 2`, the concept is the same for `MEAN_12`.

In the real dataset, there are above 3000 different IDs, and `'BIN'` ranges from `1` to `5`.

I want to pick up 'BIN' randomly like taking mean where `'BIN'` is `1`, `3`, `5` or taking sum where `'BIN'` is `4`, `5` and so on in a form of dataframe.

How to do that?

Comment: can you provide reproducible dataframe code?

Comment: It looks like a groupby with filter on the `BIN` column. However I'm a bit confused on this random possible values of bin.

Comment: `I want to pick up 'BIN' randomly like taking mean where 'BIN' is 1,3,5 or taking sum where 'BIN' is 4,5 and so on in a form of dataframe.` - can you be more specific? because `1,3,5 ` is random with length `3`, `4,5` with random `2`... Can you be more specific?

Comment: Where are in answer radomly selected groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand question need random unique `BIN`s with length `2` or `3`:

```
print (df)
    ID  AA  BB  CC  BIN
0   Z1  10  11  12    1
1   Z1   0  12  13    1
2   Z1  20  13  14    2
3   Z1  34  14  15    4
4   Z1  54  52  16    5
5   Z1  67  53  17    3
6   Z7  45  54  18    4
7   Z7  34  55  19    2
8   Z7  45  56  57    4
9   Z7  45  56  58    3
10  Z7  67  67  59    3
```

So first get all unique values:

```
v = df['BIN'].unique()
print (v)
[1 2 4 5 3]
```

And pass to [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with generated random length `2` or `3`:

```
r = np.random.choice(v, size=np.random.choice([2,3]))
print (r)
[3 5 1]

new = ''.join((str(x) for x in r))
```

Then filter rows by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and aggregate `sum` with `mean`s, last add to columns names generated `BINS` converted to `string`s with `join`:

```
df1 = df[df['BIN'].isin(r)].groupby('ID')[ 'AA', 'BB', 'CC'].agg(['mean','sum'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}_{new}')
print (df1)
    AA_mean_351  AA_sum_351  BB_mean_351  BB_sum_351  CC_mean_351  CC_sum_351
ID                                                                           
Z1        32.75         131         32.0         128         14.5          58
Z7        56.00         112         61.5         123         58.5         117
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's your pandas dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     [
...             ['Z1', 10, 11, 12, 1],
...             ['Z1', 0,  12, 13, 1],
...             ['Z1', 20, 13, 14, 2],
...             ['Z1', 34, 14, 15, 3],
...             ['Z1', 54, 52, 16, 3],
...             ['Z1', 67, 53, 17, 3],
...             ['Z7', 45, 54, 18, 1],
...             ['Z7', 34, 55, 19, 2],
...             ['Z7', 45, 56, 57, 2],
...             ['Z7', 45, 56, 58, 3],
...             ['Z7', 67, 67, 59, 3],
... 
...     ], columns=['ID', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'BIN']
... )
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df
    ID  AA  BB  CC  BIN
0   Z1  10  11  12    1
1   Z1   0  12  13    1
2   Z1  20  13  14    2
3   Z1  34  14  15    3
4   Z1  54  52  16    3
5   Z1  67  53  17    3
6   Z7  45  54  18    1
7   Z7  34  55  19    2
8   Z7  45  56  57    2
9   Z7  45  56  58    3
10  Z7  67  67  59    3
```

Now the following should do the trick:

```
# Randomly select 2 bins out of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bins = random.sample(set([1, 3, 5]), 2)

final_df = df.loc[df['BIN'].isin(bins)]\
  .groupby('ID')\
  .agg(AA_SUM_=('AA', 'sum'), AA_MEAN_=('AA', 'mean'), BB_SUM_=('BB', 'sum'), BB_MEAN_=('BB', 'mean'), CC_SUM_=('CC', 'sum'), CC_MEAN_=('CC', 'mean'))

# Rename columns accordingly
suffix = ''.join([str(x) for x in bins])
final_df.columns = [c + suffix for c in final_df.columns]
```

And the output will be:

```
    AA_SUM_12  AA_MEAN_12  BB_SUM_12  BB_MEAN_12  CC_SUM_12  CC_MEAN_12
ID                                                                     
Z1         30   10.000000         36          12         39   13.000000
Z7        124   41.333333        165          55         94   31.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random as r


def mean(listin):
    if len(listin) == 0:
        return "X"
    a = 0
    for  _i in listin:
        a += _i
    return (a)/len(listin)

def dsum(listin):
    print(listin)
    a = 0
    for  _i in listin:
        a += _i
    return a

def random_d():
    d = {"ID":"Z"+str((r.randint(0,10))),
         "AA":r.randint(0,70),
         "BB":r.randint(0,70),
         "CC":r.randint(0,70),
         "BIN":r.randint(1,3),}

    return d



def data_bin_z(z,bin1,bin2):
    z = "Z"+str(z)
    AA_SUM_name = "AA_SUM_"+str(bin1)+str(bin2)
    AA_MEAN_name = "AA_MEAN_"+str(bin1)+str(bin2)
    BB_SUM_name = "BB_SUM_"+str(bin1)+str(bin2)
    BB_MEAN_name = "BB_MEAN_"+str(bin1)+str(bin2)
    CC_SUM_name = "CC_SUM_"+str(bin1)+str(bin2)
    CC_MEAN_name = "CC_MEAN_"+str(bin1)+str(bin2)
    AA_SUM = []
    AA_MEAN = []
    BB_SUM = []
    BB_MEAN = []
    CC_SUM = []
    CC_MEAN = []

    for _dict in data:
        if _dict["ID"] == z:
            _bin = _dict["BIN"]
            if _bin == bin1 or _bin == bin2:
                AA_SUM.append(_dict["AA"])
                AA_MEAN.append(_dict["AA"])
                BB_SUM.append(_dict["BB"])
                BB_MEAN.append(_dict["BB"])
                CC_SUM.append(_dict["CC"])
                CC_MEAN.append(_dict["CC"])


    AA_SUM = dsum(AA_SUM)
    AA_MEAN = mean(AA_MEAN)
    BB_SUM = dsum(BB_SUM)
    BB_MEAN = mean(BB_MEAN)
    CC_SUM = dsum(CC_SUM)
    CC_MEAN = mean(CC_MEAN)

    ret = {"ID":z,
           AA_SUM_name:AA_SUM,
           AA_MEAN_name:AA_MEAN,
           BB_SUM_name:BB_SUM,
           BB_MEAN_name:BB_MEAN,
           CC_SUM_name:CC_SUM,
           CC_MEAN_name:CC_MEAN}

    return ret

#Put dataframe here
data = []

for _i in range(100):
    data.append(random_d())

#------------------

out_data = []
bin_combs = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5],[4,5]]
for _ID in range(10):
    for comb in bin_combs:
        out_data.append(data_bin_z(_ID,comb[0],comb[1]))


print(out_data)
```